# Java applet is not supporting the non-ascii/German characters like ä ö ü ...etc

Tags: java, windows, applet

I want to launch a browser and load a web page using Java's Runtime exec by passing parameters.Here i am trying to pass parameters to the Runtime exec from a JAVA APPLET to launch exe.

In my case, the path "C:\SW\Dr. Joanna Schöpf-Grey213982\IVLS_VS25YWTL1\ActivityLog_2014_07.xml" contains the character "ö".But, the applets passing the path as "C:\SW\Dr. Joanna Sch�pf-Grey213982\IVLS_VS25YWTL1\ActivityLog_2014_07.xml" (by replacing the "ö" german character with �) to the Runtime exec.

The applet looks like this:

```
public class LaunchSSCPApplet extends JApplet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9024284603221319628L;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    Process p = null;
    int inException = -1;
    String filesList = null;
    String filePath = null;
    String sapNumber = null;
    List<String> cmdList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private JTextPane textArea;

    public void init() {
        try {
            setupTextPanel();
            buffer = new StringBuffer();
            filePath =  getParameter("exePath");                    
            filesList =  getParameter("filesList");
            sapNumber = getParameter("sapNumber");

            buffer.append("SSCP Executable Path : "+filePath);
            if(filePath != null && !(filePath.trim().equals(""))){
                cmdList.add(filePath);

            }

            if (sapNumber != null && !(sapNumber.trim().equals(""))) {
                cmdList.add("--sap");
                cmdList.add(sapNumber);
            }

            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(filesList, "|");
            while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
                String f = tokenizer.nextToken();

                if (filePath.endsWith(".bat")) {
                    cmdList.add(f);
                } else {
                    cmdList.add("--logfile");
                    cmdList.add("C:/SW/Dr.JoannaSchöpf-Grey213982/IVLS_VS25YWTL1/ActivityLog_2014_07.xml");
                }

                buffer.append("<br>");
                buffer.append("FILE PATH: "+f);
            }

            String [] cmdArray = cmdList.toArray(new String[cmdList.size()]);

            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);
            if(filePath.contentEquals(".bat")) {
                p.waitFor();
            }

            /*
             * UnCommenting this as the Applet window has to be closed after launching SSCP
             * Defect: 235626 : Observe the applet does not close after tool is launched
             */
            JSObject win = JSObject.getWindow(this);
            win.eval("window.close()");

        } catch (IOException io) {
            buffer.append("<br>");
            buffer.append("An error occured while loading SSCP " +getStackTraceAsString(io));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            buffer.append("<br>");
            buffer.append("Please contact administrator there is some problem loading application : "+getStackTraceAsString(e));
        }
```

Please help me to fix the above problem.

Comment: Try something like:

    s = new String(getParameter("param").getBytes("8859_1"), "utf-8");

The "8859_1" may need to be replaced with an appropriate value depending on the locale of your applet.

You may need to experiment. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. tried like s = new String(getParameter("param").getBytes("8859_1"), "utf-8") and No Luck.

Comment: Can you do a getLocale in your applet and check what it returns?  It might point you in the right direction.

Comment: For Information: Your code worked correctly when I ran it on tomcat on Mac OSX 10.9.

Comment: Using weblogic as application server on windows in my project. do you think weblogic causing the problem?

Comment: I think it is Windows adding the Byte Order Mark. I checked the bytes returned and found the BOM in the sequence. Could not find a solution...